# How to merge two objects with different structure in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I Have two objects with different structure, trying to merge this two objects with matched data based on a key value, and make a new object with complete data from object1 and object2.

my Object1

```
{  
   "schedule":{  
      "onward":{  
         "journey":[  
            {  
               "trips":[  
                  {  
                     "origin":{  
                        "airportCode":"AMS"
                     },
                     "destination":{  
                        "airportCode":"BCN"
                     },
                     "FlightNumber":"KL1665"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "trips":[  
                  {  
                     "origin":{  
                        "airportCode":"AMS"
                     },
                     "destination":{  
                        "airportCode":"BCN"
                     },
                     "FlightNumber":"MF9343"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

object 2

```
{  
   "flights":[  
      {  
         "flightNumber":"KL1665",
         "price":223,
         "available":10
      },
      {  
         "flightNumber":"KL112",
         "price":223,
         "available":10
      },
      {  
         "flightNumber":" KL112",
         "price":223,
         "available":10
      }
   ]
}
```

i Would like to merge "price" and "available" to object which matches with "flightNumber" and create a new object with all data.

I have tried to use loadash and underscore but couldnt figure it. Help would be great, Thank in Advance.

Comment: final expected object
`{"schedules": {"onwardSchedules": {"trips": [{"flights": [{"origin": {"airportCode": "AMS"}, "destination": {"airportCode": "BCN"}, "marketingFlightNumber": "KL1665","price":223, "available": 10 }]
}, {"flights": [{ "origin": { "airportCode": "AMS"}, "destination": {"airportCode": "BCN"
                    
                    }
                    , "marketingFlightNumber": "MF9343"
                    
                }]

            }]
        }
    }
}
   `

Comment: you just need to do this manually.  put the data from flights you want into schedule. There isn't a "short cut" for something this specific.

Comment: @bryan60 i get this data dynamically from Ajax so manual update is not possible.

Comment: I mean you need to write the code to combine these manually with loops. There isn't a plug in solution from something like lodash or underscore for something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 simple `forEach` will do it:-

```
flights.flights.forEach(function(e, i) {
  schedule.schedule.onward.journey.forEach(function(e2, i2) {
    if (e.flightNumber == e2.trips[0].FlightNumber) {
      e2.trips[0] = $.extend(e, e2.trips[0]);
    }
  });
});
```

Working example:

```js
var schedule = {
  "schedule": {
    "onward": {
      "journey": [{
        "trips": [{
          "origin": {
            "airportCode": "AMS"
          },
          "destination": {
            "airportCode": "BCN"
          },
          "FlightNumber": "KL1665"
        }]
      }, {
        "trips": [{
          "origin": {
            "airportCode": "AMS"
          },
          "destination": {
            "airportCode": "BCN"
          },
          "FlightNumber": "MF9343"
        }]
      }]
    }
  }
};

var flights = {
  "flights": [{
      "flightNumber": "KL1665",
      "price": 223,
      "available": 10
    }, {
      "flightNumber": "KL112",
      "price": 223,
      "available": 10
    }, {
      "flightNumber": " KL112",
      "price": 223,
      "available": 10
    }

  ]
};

flights.flights.forEach(function(e, i) {
  schedule.schedule.onward.journey.forEach(function(e2, i2) {
    if (e.flightNumber == e2.trips[0].FlightNumber) {
      e2.trips[0] = $.extend(e, e2.trips[0]);
    }
  });
});

console.log(schedule);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank You so much for the reply, Can you please suggest a way in which i can get the final object in the same structure of Object 1